# How to pass index value to *ngIf expression

Tags: angular

I have a form that uses FormArray to add more tag fields. I'm using a validator on each one of the fields and I want to display error message under each field that has invalid tag entered. The problem is, I don't know how to pass index of the tag to *ngIf expression. 
I tried using:

*ngIf="commentForm.controls.i.errors.validError"

*ngIf="commentForm.controls[i].errors.validError"

*ngIf="commentForm.controls.$i.errors.validError"

but each one gives me error:

TypeError: "_co.commentForm.controls.i is undefined"

TypeError: "_co.commentForm.controls[_v.context.index] is undefined"

TypeError: "_co.commentForm.controls.$i is undefined"

How can i make it work? I'm using latest Angular.

Code: comment-form.component.html

```html
 <div formArrayName="tags">
       <h3>Tags</h3> <button (click)="addTag()">Add Tag</button>
    
       <div *ngFor="let tagname of tags.controls; let i=index">
          <label>
              Tag:
              <input type="text" [formControlName]="i">
              <div *ngIf="submitted && commentForm.controls.i.errors" class="errorbox">
                  <div *ngIf="commentForm.controls.i.errors.validError" class ="error">This tag is invalid!</div>
              </div>
          </label>
       </div>
</div>
```

comment-form.component.ts:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-comment-form',
  templateUrl: './comment-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./comment-form.component.scss']
})
export class CommentFormComponent implements OnInit {

  commentForm: FormGroup;
  submitted = false;
  success = false;

  get tags() {
    return this.commentForm.get('tags') as FormArray;
  }
  addTag() {
    this.tags.push(this.formBuilder.control(''));
  }

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.commentForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      name: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3), nameValidator()]],
      email: ['', [Validators.required, emailValidator()]],
      comment: ['', [Validators.required, commentValidator()]],
      tags: this.formBuilder.array([''], tagsValidator()) 
    });
  }

  onSubmit() {

    this.submitted = true;

    if (this.commentForm.invalid) {
        return;
    }

    this.success = true;
}

}
```

Additional info:
Adding tags works, validation on tags works, I only need to show error message when the validation returns false. And I cannot do so, because *ngIf="commentForm.controls[TAGNAME].errors.validError" doesn't work and it doesn't work because something is wrong with the way I'm passing the tagname into it

Comment: have you tried : ``commentForm.get(i).errors.validError`` ?

Comment: this one gives me following error: ERROR TypeError: "_co.commentForm.controls.get is not a function"

Comment: have you tried using `.controlsConfig` instead of `.controls`?

Comment: Has anyone figured this out? am seeing "cannot read property description of undefined" for 'placeholder="{{param?.parameterAllowedValues[0]?.description}}"'. I can't add a "?" to the beginning or end of the [0] to have it skip the null/undefined checks, because another error will occur if I do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this, the required error only shows up for given control:

```
<div formArrayName='tags'>
<div *ngFor='let control of form.controls.tags.controls;index as i'>
    Tag{{i}}: <input type='text' [formControlName]='i'>
    <span *ngIf='control.errors'>Required</span>

  </div>
```

Created a stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-conditional-ngif-formarray

Answer (score 0):

Hello to use an index you need a loop

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index">
    <a *ngIf="i % 2 = 0">Link {{ item }} number {{ i }}</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

***EDIT :***  My answer was not full, you don't need to use i in your case, simply access the value like a forEach function.
In my example, like yours {{ item }} == item == items[i]

Comment: Each tag gets its name here: [formControlName]="i" I need the name of the tag to access its errors. The name has to be entered inside *ngIf expression like this -> *ngIf="commentForm.controls.<TAGNAME>.errors.validError" but I can't seem to do this

Comment: why don't you do *ngIf="myFunction(i)" where myFunction gets the data using i ??

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the community!

It looks like you're trying to use the dot operator for access like this:

```
commentForm.controls.i.errors.validError
```

When what you want is this:

```
commentForm.controls[i].errors?.validError
```

Note that [ValidationErrors](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#errors) can be null, so you should use the question mark for safe navigation.

Comment: using *ngIf="commentForm.controls[i].errors?.validError" gives the following error ERROR TypeError: "_co.commentForm.controls[_v.context.index] is undefined

Comment: i added the ts file to the question

Answer (score 0):

The working answer is the stackblitz one. 
On top of figuring out the way to add error message to each tag it also helped me figure  out that I passed validator to tags wrongly. Correct way is to pass validator to each tag in the addTag() function, not pass it one time in ngOnInit function as I was doing.
Thanks for all the answers.